# Continuity in (X, $d_a$) iff f is continuous at a $\in$ X (special $d_a$ metric)

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let (X, d) and (Y, $d_Y$) be metric spaces and fix a point a in X.
Define $d_{a}: X$ x $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $d_a(x,x) = 0, \forall x\in X$ and $d_a(x,y) = d(x,a) + d(a,y)$ whenever x$\neq$ y.
If f: X $\rightarrow$ Y is a map, prove the following statements are equivalent:

(a) f is continuous when X is endowed with $d_a$

(b) f is continuous at a when X is endowed with $d_a$

(c) f is continuous at a when X is endowed with d

Showing (b) $\iff$ (c) is trivial since $B_{d_a}(a, \delta) = B_{d}(a, \delta)$ and (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b) follows immediately from the definition, but I am struggling to show (b) $\Rightarrow$ (a).

We want to show f is continuous at any y $\in$ X. I think I have shown for any $\epsilon \geq d_Y(f(y), f(a))$

if $\delta >0$ is such that $\forall x \in B_{d_a
}(a, \delta)$,

$f(x) \in B_{d_Y}(f(a), \epsilon - d_Y(f(y), f(a)))$

then $f(x) \in B_{d_Y}(f(y), \epsilon)$.

But how do I approach the case when $\epsilon < d_Y(f(y), f(a))$ ?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Just use that $B_{d_a}(x,\delta) = B_{d_a}(a,\delta-d(x,a))$

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I still don't see how this helps show $\forall y\in X,   \exists \delta$ s.t. $\forall x\in B_{d_a}(y, \delta), f(x) \in B_{d_a}(f(y), \epsilon)$

Comment: f continuous at a 

$\implies \forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in B_{d_a}(a, \delta), f(x) \in B_{d_Y}(f(a), \epsilon).$

$\implies \forall y\in X \forall x \in    B_{d_a}(y, \delta + d(a,y)), f(x) \in B_{d_Y}(f(a), \epsilon).$

But what about $B_{d_a}(f(a), \epsilon)$?
Thanks

@AitorIribarLopez